# Get LIKED youtube videos via API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I know how to get the count of 'liked' videos using the YouTube API, but I want to get a list of those videos.

After reading the docs, I think it can be done by getting the 'liked' playlist, but I do not know exactly how.

Can I get the 'liked' video list through the Javascript API?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're using v3 of the API, then you can get your liked video list. First, do a call to your channels feed, like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Then, in the response, you'll have a list of related playlists -- one will be keyed "likes." Take that playlist ID and request its items feed:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId={PLAYLIST_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

If you don't use v3 of the API, you probably won't have a lot of success in getting the liked videos.

Comment: Sorry for responde you so late... it's appers to be ok. But, now, I having trouble to do the simple access to the API... :(

Comment: I don't know how to get it authenticated.. I don't want to ask to user to autorize. It must be alread autorized.

Comment: In both requests you must replace &key={YOUR_API_KEY} with &acces_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}. It works only with authorized querys

Answer (score 10):

As of 2020, the `/videos` endpoint lets you filter directly for liked videos, e.g.:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?myRating=like&part=snippet
Authorization: Bearer <oauth token>
```

Comment: Anecdote of one: when I try this on my account, it's only able to see 1000 of my liked videos, when I have closer to 2000.

Answer (score 4):

If you pass the following arguments to `playlistItems.list`, you can get the liked videos' playlist associated with the authorized acccount.

```json
auth: "your_auth_key"
playlistId: "LL"
```

Here's a code snippet from the script I ran to get the liked videos in a text file. 
*Note: I used the helper code provided in the YouTube API Documentation to get the `authkey` and pass it to my function.*

```js
// get all the liked videos by a channel
async function get_liked_playlist(authkey){
    
    fs.writeFile("./output/"+"all_liked_videos"+".txt", "\n"+time_stamp, { flag: 'a+' }, e => console.log(e) );
    let nextPageToken_ = null;
    let text__ = "";
    let i = 0;

    do {

        await API.playlistItems.list({
            key: process.env.API_KEY,
            auth: authkey,
            part: "snippet",
            maxResults: 50,  // 50 is the max value
            playlistId: "LL",
            pageToken: nextPageToken_
        })
        .then(res => {
            let results = res.data.items;
            nextPageToken_ = res.data.nextPageToken;
            results.forEach(item => {
                // console.log(`Title: ${item.snippet.title}\tURL: https://youtu.be/${item.snippet.resourceId.videoId}`)        
                i++;
                text__ += "\nTitle: "+item.snippet.title+"\tURL: https://youtu.be/"+item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
            });
            console.log("items done: "+i+"\tnextPageToken: "+nextPageToken_);
        })
        .then( fs.writeFile("./output/"+"all_liked_videos"+".txt", text__ , { flag: 'a+' }, e => { if(e) console.log("error with fs\t"+e); }) )
        .then( text__ = "" )
        .catch( e => console.log("error here\t" + e) )
        
    } while (nextPageToken_ != null)

    if(text__.length>1) fs.writeFile("./output/"+"all_liked_videos"+".txt", text__ , { flag: 'a+' }, e => { if(e) console.log("error with fs\t"+e); });

}
```

Comment: Now `playlistId = LM`